# Php $_POST returns empty when using javascript to call php function

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

I am still studying php and java script.
I am creating a simple contact form and set the form action to the same page using $_Server[php_self]

What I want to do is when someone submit to my form, it will show a message including the name that was submitted on the same page. replace the contact form with the message.

I also tried pointing action to a different php page. and it still did not work. 
Does Javascript work like that? or I have to use different code or language to do that.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php 
    include 'action.php';
?>
    <title> My profle</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="contact">
   <form class="form" class="contact" id="contact-form" action="action.php" method="POST">
            Name: <br>
           <input type="text" class="field" name="name"><br>
           Number:<br>
           <input type="text" class="field" name="number"><br>
           Email:<br>
           <input type="email" class="field" name="email:>"<br>
           <br>
           <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit"
           onclick ="document.getElementById('contact-form').innerHTML='<?php thankyou();?>'">
       </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then here is the action.php

```html
<?php
    function thankyou(){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo "Thank you"." $name ! Your message has been submitted.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: P.S. the javascript returns the thankyou() function successful but the $name is missing/

Comment: You can mix js/php that way. The problem is, $_POST hasn't been set before the form is submitted. The second time you submit the form, the name should be displayed.

Comment: this wont work as want, you will have to use js to get the name for the thank you message, then submit the form to be processed in php

Comment: Sorry, mis-understood the comment

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of different problems here.

The first is a lack of understanding about the timing of when PHP and JS run.

The second is that DOM changes are lost when a new page is loaded.

This is what is happening:

1. The browser requests the page
2. The PHP runs (`$_POST` does not have a `name` key)
3. The browser gets the page
4. You click the submit button
5. The JavaScript runs, and set the `innerHTML` (remember that the PHP ran back at step 2)
6. The form submits causing the browser to navigate to a new page
7. The PHP runs again
8. The browser gets the new page … and the DOM changes make to the previous page are lost

Further reading: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

Comment: +1 for answering in an informative way that still leads to some research instead of copy and paste code. Trying to make my answers more like this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm open to hearing better ways to do this in the comments, as this is off the top of my head and I know there are better solutions... but here's what I would do in your situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> My profle</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="contact">
   <form class="form" class="contact" id="contact-form" action="" method="POST">
           <?php 
               if(isset($_POST)){
                   //process data however (I'm assuming) you need to - even if just posting to another script at this point...
                   echo 'Thank you '.$_POST['name'].' ! Your message has been submitted';
               }
               else{
                    echo 'Name: <br>
                    <input type="text" class="field" name="name"><br>
                    Number:<br>
                    <input type="text" class="field" name="number"><br>
                    Email:<br>
                    <input type="email" class="field" name="email"><br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">';
               }
           ?>
       </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I still need to study more, I'll take a look how to combine and time them correctly.
anyway, This is the demo I've been working on. 
http://resume.sofisticadoblends.com/

Comment: np, thought it might help to see some code that takes the language processing order into account correctly - although I was hoping for some more community input - I know using php and html together has a lot of best practices and some people disagree on what is actually best practice.